# Figuring out database timezone

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000, timezone

Does anybody know of a way to alter a time zone on a SQL database?

Is there any tool that could find the objects using the date and time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way I have used to see if any objects are using a particular command (e.g. those that use a local time zone, such as `GETDATE()` and `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`) is `syscomments`. The `text` column of this table in SQL 2000 has the actual command that makes up the object.

The caveat to this is if the procedure was created using `WITH ENCRYPTION` you will not be able to see or check the text column. I believe something like this should return what you are looking for:

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(ID), Text
FROM syscomments
WHERE Text LIKE '%GetDate%'
```

Comment: How is this at all the answer to the question?  It appears completely unrelated.

Comment: To the attention of @MattJohnson, as well as all the others, who may be considering a downvote on this, the issue has been raised here: http://meta.dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1007/possible-bug-in-data

Comment: @Matt I have updated both the question and this answer to make it clear why it answers the *second* part of the original question (the first part is simply to change the time zone in Windows, but the second part is to help identify those objects that that change might affect).

Comment: @AaronBertrand - Thanks, I understand now.  I was thinking about the first part of the question, which is clearly not possible, but this answer does help with the second part.  Thanks for clearing up the confusion

Answer (score 4):

Assuming SQL Server

- getdate gives local server time
- getutcdate gives utc / gmt

There is no timezone setting or changes possible inside SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

To alter the database's timezone you might be able to use something like

```
ALTER DATABASE your-database-name SET TIMEZONE TO 'AST';
```

The syntax varies from vendor to vendor. Some platforms rely on the host operating system instead. To get platform-specific answers, tag your question with the dbms you use--PostgreSQL, SQL Server, Oracle, etc.

It's not clear what objects you want to find by date and time.

Comment: This is for website reservation system and trying to find out all the stored procedures that uses getdate() on the database. Are you saying the alter database t-sql will completely change the getdate() to use that timezone?

Comment: SQL Server doesn't support `ALTER DATABASE ... SET TIMEZONE...`.